# How do you correctly use multiple instances of str_to_date with MySQL insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, str-to-date

I am trying to insert 2 dates in UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) to a MySQL database in the MySQL US date format.

I am using str_to_date. The first instance of str_to_date works as expected, but the second instance always inserts the same date as the first instance of str_to_date, even though the original dates are different.

```
$date_1 = "10/01/2016";
$date_2 = "16/02/2016";

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (date_1, date_2)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE( '$date_1', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i' ), STR_TO_DATE( '$date_2', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i' ))";
```

What is the correct way of handling multiple instances of str_to_date in a MySQL insert statement?

Thank you

Comment: can you provide your php code?

Comment: You are missing a comma (`,`) in your `VALUES` list.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `'$last_name'` also missing the value for user_id

Comment: Sorry, it was a messy example, not my original work. I have updated it now. The problem still exists.

Comment: You forgot to quote the PHP dates, so they're not dates - they're mathematical division expressions. Plus, str_to_date is used to tell mysql what the ORIGINAL date value's format is. you're saying `month/day/year`, but are providing `day/month/year`. there is no month 24 or 16...

Comment: Sorry I wrote the code out incorrectly. I have updated it now. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string of `str_to_date()` tells MySQL what format the first argument's date value is in. It's not how to format the value going in to mysql (e.g. the destination) format. str_to_date's output is ALWAYS a native mysql date/time value, which is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Since you're saying the input format is `monday/day`, but are providing `day/month` values and **NO** time values, you get wonky results.

Try

```
                         24/01/2016
STR_TO_DATE( '$date_1', '%d/%m/%Y' )
```

instead. Note the removal of the time format characters. Your input string has no time values at all.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('24/01/2016', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i');
+---------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('24/01/2016', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i') |
+---------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                        |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select str_to_date('24/01/2016', '%d/%m/%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('24/01/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2016-01-24                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Marc! I had incorrectly interpreted the str_to_date() feature.